# Insert Into Where issue (adding values to new row)

Tags: mysql

I am very new to MySQL (currently testing the MySql Workbench).

What I have created is two tables (1st Team_information , where I have columns such as Member_ID, Member_name, Team_manager)

What I am trying to do is to add the Team_manager information into another (Monthly_review) table from the same scheme (which contains the above columns as well).

Using the following statement:

```
Insert Into Monthly_review (Team_manager)
    select Team_manager
    FROM Team_information
    where Member_Name = 'Silvia Ivanova" and Member_ID = 17;
```

Please note that the above values (Silvia Ivanova and Member ID are both added in both tables "team_information" and "Monthly_review").

What happens after I execute the query is - I get the team manager name, but unfortunately not on the same row where Member ID 17 is located, but it is added to a new one.

What I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

---

With other words.

I want to:

Insert data from one table to another only if a certain condition has been met.

Another example: 
In table "Team_information" 'Silvia Ivanova' corresponds to Member_ID '17' and to a team Manager 'Ivan Petrov' . (of course I have other rows where different people have different IDs and different team managers).

In the "Monthly_review" table I have 'Silvia Ivanova" and she corresponds to member_id 17 (as the first table). What I have here is a blank column "Team_manager", where I would like to add the names of the team managers, based on lets say the member ID number.

Hope this sheds some more light.

Again, many thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want `update` rather than `insert`:

```
update Monthly_review mr join
       Team_information ti
       on ? = ?
    set mr.Team_manager = ti.team_manager
    where ti.Member_Name = 'Silvia Ivanova' and ti.Member_ID = 17;
```

It is unclear what the `join` conditions should be.  If I had to guess `ti.Member_Id = mr.Member_Id`.

Comment: Hi Gordon and many thanks for your fast answer! What I am trying to do is to populate a column based on values, which correspond to both tables. Similar to the VLOOKUP function in Excel. In few words, I want to add the team manager from the team information table, where all values were added manually to the a new table. Thanks.